# how to hide others app using xposed module from my application in android

Tags: android

I need to hide the other apps from my application. I have done using package manager but it is hiding my app icon. The code shown below

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("package", "package.MainActivity.class");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: So you mean you can successfully hide your own app using the code above, but you want to know how to do this for other apps using xposed?

Comment: yes... my intension is hiding other apps from my application.I have used above but not working to hide other apps.